Is it possible to configure an eqnarry environment to automatically split over multiple pags
Is it possible to construct an environment like eqnarray that will automatically split over multiple pages if necessary? If I have many equations that I want to present together, then it seems necessary for me to split the block up or end up with heaps of white space. While this could be fixed by brute force determining when to split these pages (and adjusting the spacing to get them to align), this would need to be redone whenever the text was edited.

Don't use eqnarray it has many flaws and is only left for backwards compatability. Use amsmath and its constructions. These can be configured to break across pages (no idea if the same configuration works on eqnarray). https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

As @dalief; mentioned in comment, should not use eqnarray and proceed with amsmath tags, like align, gather, etc. Also the option \allowdisplaybreaks helps you to break the display math to pages, and the MWE is:
\usepackage{mathools}%auto insert amsmath
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begiin{document}
...
\begin{align}
 ....
 ....
\end{align}
...
\end{document}

